# Using Anaconda’s Python interpreter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch, anaconda

I can use PyTorch in Anaconda shell:

[image]

But it does not work in Visual Studio Code:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError partially initialized module
> 'torch' has no attribute 'rand' (most likely due to a circular import)

[image]

It doesn't use Anaconda's Interpreter? How to fix it?

---

### UPDATE

I selected Anaconda's Python Interpreter from the list. Does not help.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that your script is also called torch.py. Change the name of the script and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

click on the python text on the left corner.
select anaconda if available, if not, select "enter interpreter path" and enter path to python in conda folder.